# Jquery Mobile Autocomplete JS Function as Source

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am trying to implement [jquery mobile autocomplete](http://www.andymatthews.net/code/autocomplete/) plugin. The sample usage as mentioned below.

I want to set a Javascript function for the `source` parameter, and want to make some database queries in that and return information to the page.

How can I do that? Or is there any other way that I can achieve what I want?

```
$("#searchField").autocomplete({
    target: $('#suggestions'),

    //Source is either
    source: 'data.cfc?method=search&returnformat=json&data=simple'

    //or a js object
    //autocompleteData = $.parseJSON('[{"value":"1.0","label":"Alabama"},{"value":"2.0","label":"Alaska"}]');
    source: autocompleteData

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just pass a function to the source. Though it appears to not be documented, digging through the [source code](https://github.com/commadelimited/autoComplete.js/blob/master/jqm.autoComplete-1.4.3.js) (around line 100) you can see that they can take a function for the source option.

They have a quick example in the comments of the source:

```
source:function(text,callback) { mydata = [1,2]; callback(mydata); }
```

It appears to work almost exactly the same as the regular jQuery autocomplete, where the first parameter is the text in the box and you call the second parameter and pass it your filtered data.

Comment: The jQuery UI autocomplete != [jQuery Mobile autocomplete](https://github.com/commadelimited/autoComplete.js).